# arabic language not inserting in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using MySQL database to store Arabic records, issue is when i am trying to insert records using `MySQL insert query` it will convert like this in database `&#1587;&#1593;&#1608;&#1583;` instead of Arabic word.

After google it, i found that need to set collation. So i set it to `utf8_general_ci` , `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and many other. Also i tried this before `insert query`

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET utf8;");
```

But not worked for me, Still it inserting `&#1587;&#1593;&#1608;&#1583;` in database. Where i am doing wrong?

Comment: in the table change column `collation` to `utf-8-bin`

Comment: @AK-Sonu let me try this

Comment: You should check table column's collation, probably it's not set to unicode.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardiya did you tried?

Comment: Set the charset in your database, `PHP` and in HTML where you input the data.

Comment: @AK-Sonu sorry it not worked for me

Comment: @JoSmo i set it to utf8_general_ci

Comment: Do you set it in all 3 places or only in your database?

Comment: @JoSmo all the places

Comment: And you set the charset in your database connection and your query?

Comment: Show us how you create the database connection (and don't forget to hide your username & password). :)

Comment: @JoSmo here it is :
 mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS) or die ("Couldn't connect with database!");
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die ("Database not found!");

mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1256");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET cp1256");

Comment: And how do you set the charset for `PHP`?

Comment: header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

Comment: That's for the HTML.

Comment: there is no more encoding i set

Comment: Try this `ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8')` you can check if it was applied like this `ini_get('default_charset')`

Comment: Also try to add `mysql_set_charset('utf8', $database_connection);` ater the `mysql_connect()` statement.

Comment: @JoSmo not working. tried all :)

Comment: i also tried to echo query before inserting, and then i just copy that query and inserted it using phpmyadmin and it worked, but it will not working using mysql insert query

Comment: Try to use the `MySQLi` or `PDO` driver, maybe this is fixed there, it's the more secure way anyways.

Answer (score 0):

After establish your connection, write this `MySQL` lines.

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1256");
mysql_query("set characer set cp1256");
```

[Can't insert arabic text into mysql database using mysql prompt `dba.stackexchange.com`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87385/cant-insert-arabic-text-into-mysql-database-using-mysql-prompt)

Comment: can it will work with English also? because i need both language compatible.

Comment: so use common language

Comment: read this [Multilanguage Database Design in MySQL](http://www.apphp.com/tutorials/index.php?page=multilanguage-database-design-in-mysql)

Comment: thats also not working for me. is there any other solution? or what is issue you think?

Answer (score 0):

Can u try with utf8_encode() at time of insertion and utf8_decode() function for view.

Answer (score 0):

For Arabic characters to store properly in database, you have to keep the Database charset to utf8, and database collation to utf8_general_ci. This way all your tables will have a charset of utf8.

You can also set those charset for individual tables.

The code

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
mysql_query("set characer set utf8");
```

wont work, because it sets the charset of the mysql database connection, not the database itself.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, usage of `Mysql_*` is deprecated, and no longer maintained. You should convert to `MySQLi` or `PDO` for security reasons.

Here's a few pointers:

- **ALL** attributes must be set to UTF-8 or UTF-8 w/o BOM (collation is NOT the same as charset)
- Save the document as UTF-8 or UTF-8 w/o BOM (If you're using Notepad++, it's Format -> Convert to UFT-8 or UTF-8 w/o BOM

  - Note that even though they both are UTF-8, they behave somewhat different
- The header in both PHP and HTML should be set to UTF-8

  - HTML: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`
  - PHP: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`
- Upon connecting to the database, set the charset to UTF-8 there as well, like this: `mysql_set_charset("utf8");` (directly after connecting, this is for `MySQL`, there are similar ones for `MySQLi_*` and PDO).
- Also make sure your database and tables are set to UTF-8, you can do that like this:

`ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`

`ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`

Remember that EVERYTHING that can be set to a specific charset, needs to be set to UFT-8 (If you're using another charset, everything needs to be set to that), otherwise you will get some weird characters in your database. This will also work for English characters, so don't worry about that. Hope this helped!

Comment: thanks for the answer. i will follow this steps and let you know :)